# 2011 Acura RDX alarm random trigger

Tags: obd-ii, acura, alarm, rdx

I have a 2011 Acura RDX and the alarm is going off a random times (usually middle of the night).  Based on suggestions online, I have replaced the battery in the two remotes, but it still happens.

I also read that the hood open switch may be intermittent, but I can't find it!  Does this vehicle have such a switch?  If not, does an alarm event set an OBD2 code with freeze frame that will tell me which sensor triggered the alarm?

Comment: I am not sure about your RDX, but I *believe* your alarm is controlled by the body control module. (BCM). This seems a likely culprit for what you're experiencing. Again, I do not have direct experience with the RDX so don't know for sure, but it might be an avenue to pursue. The OBDII will not tell you anything in this case.  Something else to consider is, are you sure someone isn't pranking you?

Comment: You can see the [hood ajar switch](https://wieck-honda-production.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/bd1a8d73e431ac003857bd46d9e94b70970e7e78/preview-928x522.jpg) in the far left part of this image. It is about a 1/4 of the way up. It is basically a tab hanging out with the switch in it. It looks [like this](https://www.autozone.com/electrical-and-lighting/hood-ajar-indicator-switch/p/duralast-hood-ajar-indicator-switch-sw3051/413334_0_0).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I don't see the switch in the picture.  Could you give me an approximate location?  I'm looking along the body at the edge where the hood would come down.  (And no pranksters involved, it's going off in my garage at night)

Comment: In the picture, it is painted silver with a black dot in the middle of it. If you divided the image up into 10 equal sections along the left side, it would be about 2.5 sections up from the bottom. There is a silver piping (from the AC) which goes underneath of it. It is between the wiper fluid bottle and the headlight. In the vehicle it is mounted to the right fender (passenger side in a left hand drive vehicle you'd see here in the States).

Comment: Got it thanks - I thought that was a valve on the AC line.  I will update question if I can can more info from next alarm trigger.  (From OBD2 scanner)

Comment: As I stated, the OBD2 scanner won't tell you any about the alarm or why it alarmed.

Comment: @paulster2. I had this same problem with a Ford. I believe it was a Fusion around a 2010. The OBDll scan revealed a fault in passenger door switch. Repaired that and all was well. I don't know what an Acura is like though.

Comment: @Paulster2.  There is no such part on my 2011 RDX.  The only black thing in that area is a bumper used to adjust hood close height.  Perhaps this model has no hood ajar sensor?